# Solve the equation $8^x+3\cdot2^{2-x}=1+2^{3-3x}+3\cdot2^{x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$8^x+3\cdot2^{2-x}=1+2^{3-3x}+3\cdot2^{x+1}$$ The given equation is equivalent to $$2^{3x}+\dfrac{12}{2^x}=1+\dfrac{8}{2^{3x}}+6\cdot2^x$$ If we put $a:=2^x>0$, the equation becomes $$a^3+\dfrac{12}{a}=1+\dfrac{8}{a^3}+6a$$ which is $$a^6-6a^4-a^3+12a^2-8=0$$ The LHS factors as $(a+1)(a-2)(a^4+a^3-3a^2-2a+4)$, which is in no case obvious. Let's say that we find the roots $1$ and $-2$, then how do we show that $(a^4+a^3-3a^2-2a+4)$ does not factor any more? Taking these into consideration, I believe there is an another approach. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: "*how do we show that (degree-4 polynomial) does not factor any more?*"  Every complex polynomial can factor into linear components with complex coefficients as per the fundamental theorem of algebra, however not necessarily into factors with integer coefficients.  There does exist a generic formula for quartics and below using "elementary" functions such as n'th roots and the like, however no such generic formula exists for quintics or higher (*though special cases may exist*).  Actually *performing* such a factoring however can be very difficult.

Comment: the remaining factor $a^4 + a^3 - 3 a^2 -2a + 4$  has no real roots:  it is always positive.

Comment: Hint : let $$a=2^x$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Let's start from

$$a^3+\dfrac{12}{a}=1+\dfrac{8}{a^3}+6a$$

Now rewrite it as

$$\left[a^3-\left(\frac2a\right)^3\right]-6\left[a-\frac 2a\right]-1=0$$
$$\left(a-\frac2a\right)\left[a^2+\frac{4}{a^2}-4\right]-1=0$$
$$\left(a-\frac2a\right)^3-1=0$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Because, $a^2+4/a^2-4=(a-2/a)^2$

Comment: Thanks, I got it! A really nice observation!

Answer (score 0):

Letting $y=2^{x-\frac12}>0$

$$\begin{align}8^x+3\cdot2^{2-x}=1+2^{3-3x}+3\cdot2^{x+1}&\iff y^3+\frac3y=\frac1{2\sqrt2}+\frac1{y^3}+3y
\\&\iff\left(y-\frac1y\right)^3=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^3\\&\iff\dots\\&\iff y=\sqrt2\\&\iff x=1.\end{align}$$